# Ticks not updating with slider and only positve quadrand of a plot visible in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I am trying to draw a simplified top-down perspective of a wing. I am using sliders to change the wingspan (b) and wing surface (S).

I am using matplotlib.patch.Polygon to draw it symmetrically from the 0,0 point. But only the positive quarter is visible and plot limits are not updating with sliders. x and y max ticks are stuck at 1 and 1. The goal is to see the whole wing in the center of the plot with ticks updating.

The code below is a modified showcase from: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html

code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, Slider

%matplotlib widget
# Define initial parameters
init_S = 50
init_b = 50

# Create the figure and the polygon that we will manipulate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((-init_b/2, -(init_S/init_b)/2), init_b, init_S/init_b, alpha=0.4))
ax.set_xlabel('Wingspan [m]')
ax.set_xlabel('Chord [m]')

# adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# Make a horizontal slider to control the wingspan
axb = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
b_slider = Slider(axb, r"Wingspan [$m$]", 0.1, 50, init_b, orientation="horizontal")

# Make a vertically oriented slider to control the surface 
axsurf = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.25, 0.0225, 0.63])
S_slider = Slider(axsurf, r"Surface [$m^2$]", 0.1, 50, init_S, orientation = "vertical")

# The function to be called anytime a slider's value changes
def update(val):
    ax.cla() # clear plot before update
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((-b_slider.val/2, -(S_slider.val/b_slider.val)/2), b_slider.val, S_slider.val/b_slider.val, alpha=0.4))
    plt.autoscale()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# register the update function with each slider
b_slider.on_changed(update)
S_slider.on_changed(update)

# Create a `matplotlib.widgets.Button` to reset the sliders to initial values.
resetax = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    S_slider.reset()
    b_slider.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I recommend writing a simplified version that still produces the same issue. People on this site will help with debugging, but the longer the code the less likely someone will want to spend the time on it.

Comment: I hope this edit helps. I replaced the long polygon xy function with rectangle and contained all function/class inputs into a single line since they are not crucial to the problem. Shortened the code from around 90 lines to 48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to do so is to define a Polygon and plot it within an update function, then use interact from ipywidgets to make the sliders, where you can set the limits, steps and initial values of variables:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from ipywidgets import *

def update(b, S):

    a = S/b
    polygon = Polygon([[-b/2, -a/2],
                       [b/2, -a/2],
                       [b/2, a/2],
                       [-b/2, a/2]])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.fill(*polygon.exterior.xy, alpha=0.4)
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$ [m]')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$ [m]')
    ax.set_title(f'wingspan = {b} m,   surface area = {S} m$^2$')
    plt.show()

interact(update,
         b=widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=20, step=1, value=10),
         S=widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=400, step=10, value=50))
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the limits according to the plot content, you can use [`autoscale()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.autoscale.html), which scales the axis view to the data:

Once in the update function:

```py
def update(val):
    ax.cla() # clear plot before update
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(polygonxy(S_slider.val, b_slider.val, rttr, sw_angle), True, alpha=0.4))
    ax.autoscale()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

And once at the end of the script (for initial autoscaling):

```
# [...]
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the result is the same. Ticks stuck at 1, with only the positive quadrant visible. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Interesting... which matplotlib version are you using @PatrikHlebecŠtor? Are you working with jupyter or "stand-alone"?

Comment: I am using a Jupyter Notebook. I am primarily editing in VS Code, and checking for bugs in the browser since sometimes works better there. Matplotlib version 3.5.1, updated with Anaconda.

Comment: thanks for the update! Since your question was answered to your satisfaction, I will not look further into this.